# Getting the current state of NSButtonCell in an NSMatrix

Tags: cocoa, nsmatrix

I'm using an NSMatrix as a keypad and calling:

```
[selectedCell setEnabled:NO];
[selectedCell setTransparent:YES];
```

when a key is selected (to prevent the same operation being performed again). However, I'd also like the option of 'flipping' the entire selections when done -- that is, replacing all the *deleted* cells and hiding the remaining *(unselected)* ones.

Is it possible to loop through all the cells of my matrix and check their enabled/transparent state using something like:

```
if([selectedCell isEnabled] == NO)
  NSLog(@"the cell is disabled");
if([selectedCell isTransparent] == YES)
  NSLog(@"the cell is transparent");
```

The above code doesn't work of course, but you get the idea... I'm a relative newbie, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSMatrix lets you get [the number of columns](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMatrix/numberOfColumns) and [the number of rows](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMatrix/numberOfRows), and [the cell at a specific row and column](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMatrix/cellAtRow:column:). So, do that in a couple of `for` loops.

Going by tag can work, but requires that you give every cell its own tag, and (in the example you show) that all the tags are in a series. Any odd numbers out, duplicate tags, or untagged cells will cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Peter. That's a lot cleaner way to do it and also obviates the need to 'hard-wire' the matrix size into the app. Appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I use `NSNumber` to store the selected index of the radio group (handled as `NSMatrix` in the Interface Builder). To realize this I synthesize a member variable for which I set the "Selected Index" **binding** of the radio group.

```
@interface MyClass {
  NSNumber* m_selectedIndex;
}
@property (readwrite, assign) NSNumber* selectedIndex;
```

Additionally, I added an enum to make values human readable.

```
typedef enum { APPLE = 0, PLUM = 1 } SELECTION_STATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!!
Okay guys, I've solved this with:

```
for(key=1; key <= 16; key++)
if([[numericKeypad cellWithTag:key] isTransparent] == YES)
    // ...or alternatively...
    // if([[numericKeypad cellWithTag:key] isEnabled:NO])
    {
    [[numericKeypad cellWithTag:key] setTransparent:NO];
    [[numericKeypad cellWithTag:key] setEnabled:YES];
    }
else
    {
    //...disable it...
    }
```

Seems I was pretty close all along, but I struggled for an entire day trying to find the right syntax due to inexperience. Thanks a lot anyhow :-)